# SublimeText no muestra resultados en Terminal zsh al correr con un build system

Tags: python, terminal, sublimetext3, zsh

Tengo una macbook pro con SO Monterey y usando **Sublime Text 3**, quiero correr el código:

```
print("Hola mundo")
```

Tengo instalado **python 3.10.4** y para que el resultado de cada código se vea en mi terminal (uso **zsh**), escribí el siguiente código en:

> /Users/usuario/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
> 3/Packages/User/Python310.sublime-build

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "osascript -e 'tell app \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd $file_path && python3 -u $file\"'",
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
}
```

Como resultado, se abre una terminal que dice lo siguiente:

```
Last login: Fri Dec 29 21:29:19 on ttys000
➜  ~ cd /Users/usuario/ruta_completa && python3 -u /Users/usuario/ruta_completa/Prueba.py
cd: too many arguments
➜  ~
```

Alguien podría ayudarme a encontrar el error? Qué es lo que tengo mal configurado?

Comment: La causa mas común es que algún directorio de tu ruta o tu propio script de python tenga un nombre con espacios en el, por ejemplo `cd /home/fulanito/Documentos/Tutorial Python/test.py` generaria ese error.  La solución mas simple suele ser englobar la ruta entre comillas, algo como     `"shell_cmd": "osascript -e 'tell app \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd \'$file_path\' && python3 -u \'$file\'\"'",`

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla sos un genio! Quité todos los espacios de la ruta del archivo y volví a correr el print sin modificar el código de builld-system y ahora sí muestra el resultado en una terminal. Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejo aclarado que pude solucionar el problema con la respuesta de @FJSevilla.
Muchas gracias!

Lo que FJSevilla indicó fue:

> La causa mas común es que algún directorio de tu ruta o tu propio
> script de python tenga un nombre con espacios en el, por ejemplo cd
> /home/fulanito/Documentos/Tutorial Python/test.py generaria ese error.
> La solución mas simple suele ser englobar la ruta entre comillas, algo
> como "shell_cmd": "osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script
> "cd '$file_path' && python3 -u '$file'"'", –  FJSevilla

Lo que yo hice fue quitar los espacios en la ruta al archivo test.py. Siguiendo el ejemplo de FJSevilla, la ruta al archivo me quedó así:

/home/fulanito/Documentos/Tutorial-Python/test.py

Y no toqué el código del buil-system de Sublime Text 3.

Comment: Si te sirvió lo que comentó @FJSevilla, pedile que redacte un respuesta, o redactá por tu cuenta la respuesta que te ha sido útil, para luego poder [aceptarla](/help/closed-questions). Recordá que la zona de respuestas es para respuestas completas a la pregunta, no para comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

-te recomiendo que utilice visual estudio code
-revisa la variable PATCH del sistema. asegúrate de que la ruta
al ejecutable de Python (python3 o Python) este incluido en la variable
PATH es esencial para ejecutar scripts y programas Python desde
la línea de comandos
-python3 --version  <-ejecuta este comando en la terminal para ver si es detectado

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Sí, la versión que tengo según la terminal, al ejecutar python3 -V o python3 --version es Python 3.10.4. Por eso, no sé cuál puede ser el error en el código. Por las dudas pregunto, tengo que reemplazar $file_path por la ruta en donde está el ejecutable de Python o está bien que haya escrito el código tal cual está sin reemplazar nada?